# How can I add a continuous beep sound which frequency I change really quickly

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a visualization of the quick sort algorithm in c# wpf, and I wanted to add sound to it. Can I change the frequency of something like the `Console.Beep` while its playing?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consult the [.NET API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=net-6.0) of the .NET class you want to use? This should be your first place to go. Bookmark this page. Entering the class name into a web search engine will usually yield you a direct link to class' API documentation.

See the API documentation to learn more about [`Console.Beep` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-6.0#system-console-beep(system-int32-system-int32)) and its limitations.

`Console.Beep` supports a frequency range of 37 Hz to 32.767 kHz (the real limitation should be the speaker's range).

```cs
int frequencyInHertz = 60;
int durationInMilliseconds = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds;
Console.Beep(frequencyInHertz, durationInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: That api is no longer supported

Comment: What are you talking about? It is still supported/part of the .NET framework.

Comment: “The Beep method is not supported on the 64-bit editions of Windows Vista and Windows XP.”

Comment: Yes, exactly. I gave the hint to read the docs to learn about the limitations. If he's using an other version than 64 bit Vista or XP, the method is still supported.

Comment: It works on 64 bit Windows 10 for example as it is neither Vista nor XP.